# Android: how to open a Google Map?

Tags: android, google-maps

I have an activity which extends MapActivity. After running the activity, the Google Map should be shown on the emulator.
How can I do that?

Comment: A MapActivity shows a Google Map. Be more specific.

Comment: "If you ask a vague question, you’ll get a vague answer. But if you give us details and context, we can provide a useful answer." - [How to Ask FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

http://www.vogella.de/articles/AndroidLocationAPI/article.html#overview_maps
This link got what u need.
i did it. and it works for me as well..
Just move to the 4th topic from the Index. (Google Maps)

Thanks

**UPDATED:**
**Menifest File:**

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="de.vogella.android.locationapi.maps" android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0">
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="10" />

<application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name">
    <activity android:name=".ShowMap" android:label="@string/app_name">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <uses-library android:required="true" android:name="com.google.android.maps"></uses-library>

</application>
```

**XML LayoutFile:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/mainlayout"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

<com.google.android.maps.MapView
    android:id="@+id/mapview"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:apiKey="Your Maps API Key"
/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

**ACtivity:**

import com.google.android.maps.GeoPoint;
import com.google.android.maps.MapActivity;
import com.google.android.maps.MapController;
import com.google.android.maps.MapView;

public class ShowMap extends MapActivity {

```
private MapController mapController;
private MapView mapView;
private LocationManager locationManager;

public void onCreate(Bundle bundle) {
    super.onCreate(bundle);
    setContentView(R.layout.main); // bind the layout to the activity

    // create a map view
    RelativeLayout linearLayout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.mainlayout);
    mapView = (MapView) findViewById(R.id.mapview);
    mapView.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
    mapView.setStreetView(true);
    mapController = mapView.getController();
    mapController.setZoom(14); // Zoon 1 is world view
    locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0,
            0, new GeoUpdateHandler());
}

@Override
protected boolean isRouteDisplayed() {
    return false;
}

public class GeoUpdateHandler implements LocationListener {

    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        int lat = (int) (location.getLatitude() * 1E6);
        int lng = (int) (location.getLongitude() * 1E6);
        GeoPoint point = new GeoPoint(lat, lng);
        mapController.animateTo(point); //  mapController.setCenter(point);
    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
    }
}
}
```

Comment: I got this exception `03-28 10:03:05.978: E/AndroidRuntime(354): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-28 10:03:05.978: E/AndroidRuntime(354): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.williamroma.example/com.williamroma.example.GoogleMapActivity}: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.williamroma.example.GoogleMapActivity in loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[/data/app/com.williamroma.example-1.apk]
`

Answer (score 2):

for starting mapview then follow this [mapview's link](http://www.bogotobogo.com/Android/android17MapView.html)

Answer (score 1):

You have to signup [here](http://code.google.com/android/maps-api-signup.html) and then insert the code provided in your layout like this:

```
<com.google.android.maps.MapView
    android:id="@+id/map_map"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:apiKey="***************************************"
/>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can refer this link, http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-mapview.html

Check if you have provided your Map API key properly. This link has helped me to display the map with my present location.